# Flask installation error with virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I want to setup flask so I follow the instructions on  Flask installation website. I got error when I used "virtualenv venv".Meanwhile version of python is 2.7.6

```
semihy@semihy-Inspiron-5537:~/Masaüstü/flaskproject$ virtualenv env
New python executable in env/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: The executable env/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/home/semihy/Masa\xfcst\xfc/flaskproject' (should be u'/home/semihy/Masa\xfcst\xfc/flaskproject/env')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have special characters in your file-path. 
`/home/semihy/Masa\xfcst\xfc/flaskproject`

You will need to create a folder in a new location with only valid ASCII characters, e.g.
`/home/semihy/Masa/flaskproject`